# Как вывести инлайн кнопки по 2 в ряду

Tags: telegram

Есть вот такой код. Меню для телеграм с инлайн кнопками. Кнопки всегда выводятся в 2 ряда, первый ряд 2 кнопки, второй ряд все остальные. Если во 2 ряду кнопок больше чем 3, то текст на них сокращается и становиться не читаемый. Подскажите, как сделать вывод кнопок меню по 2 в ряду?

```html
var button = [{name: 'меню',button: ['Комната 1','Комната 2','Закрыть','меню']},
            {name: 'Комната 1',button: ['Действие 6','Действие 7','Назад','Закрыть','меню']},
            {name: 'Комната 2', button: ['Действие 1','Действие 2','Действие 3','Действие 4','Действие 5','Назад','Закрыть','меню']}
];


var menuUp = 'меню';
var first_tap = false;

on({id: "telegram.0.communicate.request", ack: false, change: 'any'}, function (obj) {
    command = obj.state.val.substring(obj.state.val.indexOf(']')+1);
    user = obj.state.val.substring(obj.state.val.indexOf('[')+1,obj.state.val.indexOf(']'));
//************************************
// меню
//************************************
    var menu = {
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [[],[]],
        }
    };
    
    log("message_id = " + getState("telegram.0.communicate.requestMessageId").val);
    log("menuUp = " + menuUp);
    if (command === 'меню') first_tap = true;
    if (command === 'Назад') command = menuUp;
    var but1 = getButtonArray(button, 'name', command).toString();
    
    if (but1.length > 0) {          // проверяем, что строка не пустая
        var but2 = but1.split(','); //преобразуем в массив
        menuUp = but2.pop();        //вырезаем последний элемент
        log ("but2 = " + JSON.stringify(but2));
        if (but2.length > 0) {      // проверяем что массив не пуст
            var index = 0;
            for (var i=0, len=but2.length; i<len; i++) {
                if ((i > 1)&&(index < 1)) index = ++index;
                menu.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[index].push({ text: but2[i], callback_data: but2[i]});
            }
            log(JSON.stringify(menu.reply_markup.inline_keyboard));
            if (first_tap) {
                sendTo('telegram.0', {user: user, text: 'Меню ' + command, reply_markup: menu.reply_markup});
                first_tap = false;
            } else sendTo('telegram', { 
                    user: user, 
                    text: 'Меню ' + command, 
                    editMessageText: { 
                        options: { 
                            chat_id: getState("telegram.0.communicate.requestChatId").val, 
                            message_id: getState("telegram.0.communicate.requestMessageId").val, 
                            reply_markup: menu.reply_markup
                        }    
                    } 
                });
        }
    } else log("but1 пуст");
    
//************************************
// Команды
//************************************
    // ищем в тексте команды 
    if (command ==="Действие 1") {
        //тут код что надо сделать
        CommandDone();
    }

    if (command ==="Закрыть") {
        sendTo('telegram', {
            user: user,
            text:   'Конец',
            editMessageText: {
                options: {
                    chat_id: getState("telegram.0.communicate.requestChatId").val, 
                    message_id: getState("telegram.0.communicate.requestMessageId").val,
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

function CommandDone(){
    sendTo('telegram', {
        user: user,
        text:   'Выполняю...',
        editMessageText: {
            options: {
                chat_id: getState("telegram.0.communicate.requestChatId").val, 
                message_id: getState("telegram.0.communicate.requestMessageId").val,
            }
        }
    });
}

function getButtonArray(obj, keyName, Name) {
    var result = [];
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj[attr] && typeof obj[attr] === 'object') {
            result = result.concat(getButtonArray(obj[attr], keyName, Name));
        }
        if (attr === keyName && obj[attr] === Name) {
            result.push(obj.button);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вот как выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Расположение кнопок зависит от созданных массивов. Сначала идет массив **клавиатура**, затем в него вложенный массив **ряд**, затем в ряд **кнопка**. А как построить массив уже не имеет значение, в моем случае выглядит это так:

```
    $keyboard = array(
        "keyboard" => array(
            array(
                array(
                    "text" => " Новости"
                ),
                array(
                    "text" => "ℹ Информация"
                )
            ),
            array(
                array(
                    "text" => " Промокод",
                )               
            )
        ),
        "one_time_keyboard" => false, 
        "resize_keyboard" => true
    );
```

вот скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]